# What happens when we call IUnknown::Release

Tags: directx, directx-11

For example, in the following code:

```
ID3D11Texture2D* texture2d; 

    HRESULT result = mSwapChain->GetBuffer(0, __uuidof(ID3D11Texture2D), (LPVOID*) &texture2d);//mSwapChain is a swap chain, as obvious

    result = mDevice->CreateRenderTargetView(texture2d, 0, &mTargetView);

    texture2d->Release();
```

I am really confused what will happen to the backbuffer in the swapchain after calling release. At the moment what I think might be happening is, the pointer is released, without affecting the backbuffer itself. I need a more elaborate answer though, since I am having difficulty understanding the concept.

Comment: See [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/prog-dx-with-com). Referencing counting is basically 'manual garbage collection'. See also [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_counting).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The texture object maintains an internal count of the number of "references" it has. Initially when your code starts, the swapchain internally has a pointer to the texture so it has a reference count of one.

When it returns a pointer to you, there are now two references to the object.

Note that the code internally to swapchain::GetBuffer does this manually by calling the AddRef function of the texture before returning the pointer to you.

So when you call Release all it does it reduce the reference count by one and then say "Ah, there is still one reference so I'll do nothing else."

If the swap chain object had been deleted before you called your Release on the texture, it would have "released" it's reference to the texture, so when you called your Release it would have reduced the texture's reference count to zero and it would have said "Ah, nobody is using me any more, I'll delete myself!".

So basically you calling Release on the texture is just you telling the texture that you are not interested in it any more. It will still hang around in memory though until everyone has told it that.

Comment: One minor note: With Direct3D it uses 'deferred destruction' so once your resource hits a refcount of 0, it's eligible for destruction but it may be a few frames before it's actually freed.